# How can I use Stripe API to retrieve the list of all card issuers for all cards? (in Python or JS)

Tags: stripe-payments

I can't figure out if it is possible to retrieve a table like this from Stripe API:

| Card_id | Card_issuer |
| --- | --- |
| id_1 | Issuer_1 |
| id_2 | Issuer_2 |
| id_3 | Issuer_2 |

I have tried this (with my API key) in Python:

```
def get_card_issuers():
    card_issuers = set()
    customers = stripe.Customer.list(limit=100)
    for customer in customers.data:
        sources = stripe.Customer.list_sources(customer.id, object="card", limit=5)
        for source in sources.data:
            if source.issuer:
                card_issuers.add(source.issuer)
    return card_issuers

if __name__ == "__main__":
    all_card_issuers = get_card_issuers()
    print("List of all card issuers for all customers:")
    for issuer in all_card_issuers:
        print(issuer)
```

But it returns nothing. Except I'm sure all my customers have a card, and an associated card_issuer.

Could you please help me with that?

Thank you very much!

Comment: The "issuer" field is not available in the public API. If you need to access it, you can try reaching out to Stripe Support to see if they have any feature that can allow you to do so. Also, Stripe doesn't recommend using the deprecated Sources API. They recommend that you adopt the PaymentMethods API.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer Alex, and sorry for the delay!